# Using mutableStateOf instead of observeAsState

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working with Jetpack Compose in an Android app and had the problem that my uiState (LiveData) was set to its initial value on every recomposition, since I've initialized it like

```
val authUiState: AuthUIState by authenticationViewModel.uiState.observeAsState(AuthUIState.Loading)
```

It was set to Loading on every recomposition before it was set to the correct value.
When I tried to *Remember* the value, I learned that we can't use observeAsState within the remember block and finally changed it to

```
val authUiState = remember{ mutableStateOf(authenticationViewModel.uiState.value) }.value
```

This works, but I'm not quite sure, if this is the common and good way to solve this.
What do you think? Should I do it differently? Do you need more information?

Comment: U can initialize `uiState` without using the default value i guess:- `val authUiState: AuthUIState by authenticationViewModel.uiState.observeAsState()`

Comment: @jpm, Any reason you just deleted the question on coroutines? I thought it was a good question and would be helpful to others, and I took time to clearly answer it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 , sorry. Your answer didn't really solved my problem and I noticed that the question was not really clear, even to me. So I'll work with my current solution until I'm a litlle more clear about what I actually need  and either can solve it myself, or come back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the `uiState` inside your viewmodel is something like a LiveData Object, (which is kinda what it seems like from the code), the recommended way is to store it in the viewmodel itself as mutable state.

```
var uiState by mutableStateOf (initialValue)
private set //Do not allow external modifications to maintain consistency of state

fun onUiStateChange(newValue: Any){
uiState = newValue
}
```

You just need to initialise it as a MutableState, in the rest of the code, to update, delete or whatever you want to do with it, just treat it as a regular variable. Compose will trigger recomposition every time the value is updated.

The following code snippet below will almost certainly not work, because here, the state is whatever you wrap inside mutableStateOf(), which is just a simple value which will be fetched once from the viewmodel and then remembered throughout recompositions, so no code change will be triggered here

```
val authUiState by remember{ mutableStateOf(authenticationViewModel.uiState.value) }
```

Storing state in the viewmodel as mutableState, is as far as my knowledge extends, the best practice in compose. You will see the same in the 'State Codelab' from Android developers

Good luck

Comment: Thank you, that works. And looks  much nicer :)

Comment: Glad to help :)